# Cannot connect to the AWS web console from another computer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had a migration project of website from one hosting to Amazon web services, So I opened AWS account on my name and when I finish the project I wanted to change everything to the company name (obviously was wrong idea), I manage to change everything but the problem is when the client wants to connect with the username and password I gave him he cannot connect and getting error message of wrong username and password, meanwhile I am able to connect with the same login details.

(I checked the user and password many times and actually try to connect via client computer many times and also could not connect)

Is anyone had this issue before?
Is anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create an IAM account and grant it all privileges but there was no way to change the credit card using the IAM account, even though I granted payment privileges.

The only solution was to contact AWS customer services and tell them that I cannot connect from another computer to my account. They fixed something on their side and my customer could now connect.